# Android, C#: Passing a bitmap to another activity ends the app without warning

Tags: c#, android

I have tried both: Passing a bitmap directly from one activity to another - would not work. After the activity was about to start it returned "system failed". 
So I've decided to convert the bitmap into a bytearray and then pass said aray over to the other activity. This ends in the result, that the app doesnt crash. It just ends itself. No warning. As if I was to call "finish()" and have nothing else open. All I am doing is this:

```
    private void OnItemClick(object sender, int position)
    {
        if(RecViewLay != (int)RecyclerLayout.Friends)
        {
            //Convert Bitmap to ByteArray
            Bitmap bm = loadPhotos.pictures[position].Picture;
            byte[] bitmapData;
            using (var stream1 = new MemoryStream())
            {
                bm.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 100, stream1);
                bitmapData = stream1.ToArray();
            }

            var activity2 = new Intent(this, typeof(Activity_RecyclerView_Comments));
            activity2.PutExtra("galleryType", 0); // 0 neuste, 1 beste
            activity2.PutExtra("picturesinarow", 1); // gridbilder
            activity2.PutExtra("recyclerLayout", (int)RecyclerLayout.Comments_Singles); // unterschiedliche layouts
            activity2.PutExtra("hasHeader", true);
            activity2.PutExtra("thumbnails", false);
            activity2.PutExtra("RecViewLayout", (int)RecyclerViewLayouts.Userpicture_FullScreen);
            activity2.PutExtra("BitmapInByteArray", bitmapData);
            Activity_RecyclerView.gallery = false;
            activity2.PutExtra("finalActivity", (int)RecviewHeader.Userpicture_FullScreen); // What Activity do we want to see?

            //soleley for userpic fullsc
            activity2.PutExtra("username", loadPhotos.pictures[position].username);
            activity2.PutExtra("taskID", loadPhotos.pictures[position].taskID);

            StartActivity(activity2);
        }


    }
```

Is there something that would case that? Do you guys maybe have any other way of passing a bitmap between activities?

Thanks!

Comment: save the bitmap to disk then send the path

Comment: Okay .. how would I go on about that? And about the receiving?